# Git merge while switching to submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-merge

We are using Qooxdoo framework in our application. For now, it's copy is stored in our Git repository in the root folder "qooxdoo". We have decided to replace that with submodule pointing directly to GitHub Qooxdoo repository, so we can checkout new versions in future more easily.

I created branch for these changes based on master, called qooxdoo-update. Removed old folder completely and added submodule for qooxdoo.

> git rm -r qooxdoo
>   git submodule add git://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo.git qooxdoo

So far this works pretty good. However problem arise when I want to merge master into this branch to keep it updated till other developers can test their code againts new version.

While still in qooxdoo-update branch I issue command:

> **git merge origin/master**
>
> CONFLICT (file/directory): There is a directory with name qooxdoo in origin/master. Adding qooxdoo as qooxdoo~HEAD

then...

> **git status**
>   Unmerged paths:
>      (use "git add/rm ..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
>
> ```
>    added by us:        qooxdoo
> ```

running...

> **git rm qooxdoo**
>   qooxdoo: needs merge
>   rm 'qooxdoo'
>   Unlink of file 'qooxdoo' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)

or...

> **git add qooxdoo**
>   error: unable to index file qooxdoo
>   fatal: updating files failed

So i am not really sure how to resolve that conflict to successfully finish merging.

Comment: If you run `git mergetool` it should give you the option of taking theirs or keeping yours IIRC.  mergetool is usually the easiest way of resolving conflicts.

Comment: Yeah, i know about, but that's doesn't solve a thing. I have here also the TortoiseGit and tried resolving conflict there, but ended with same error messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git error: unable to index file Crashlytics.framework/Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580948/git-error-unable-to-index-file-crashlytics-framework-headers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git rm -rf qooxdoo` command should have been done in its own commit, followed by the submodule addition. That will tell git (when merging from master into branch) about the intentions. Currently, the same commit being merged is just replacing the files/contents - so git gets confused. Any chance you can replay the master commit?

Comment: Sorry, that repo is long gone, so I cannot test it. However you answer seems logical, so it's your ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to come back to the previous recent version of your file/dir, executing:

```
git reset HEAD qooxdoo
```

should work.