# git error: unable to index file Crashlytics.framework/Headers

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am using Twitter's Fabric on my iOS app.

Crashlytics in Fabric just updated itself and now I cannot commit my project to `git`. I get the error:

> git error: unable to index file `Crashlytics.framework/Headers`
>
> fatal: updating files failed

[image]

Any idea what is going wrong or how to fix it?

Running `git status` reveals:

```
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

Crashlytics.framework/Info.plist
Fabric.framework/Info.plist
profile.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/
profile.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/
```

Comment: Could you go to the directory and do `git status` and then a `git remote -v` and put the output here?

Comment: @gran_profaci I added some pertinent `git status` output. as for `git remote -v` it just showed my github repository for both push and fetch

Comment: Did you try re-adding your repo in Xcode Preferences > Source Control?

Comment: @gran_profaci no. I need to re add it?

Comment: You could always ensure it's working fine. You could also try cleaning your workspace by a clean build and also a `git clean -f -d`

Comment: @avnishkgaur Yes. I just posted an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it by using sourcetree.. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Going into terminal and manually committing to git solved the issue. All my further commits in xcode have worked since.

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```

Answer (score 11):

I think this relates to the git submodule since I had similar issue. However adding or removing it didn't help. What worked was reseting it into HEAD version, e.g.

```
git reset HEAD problematic_file_or_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

The same issue happen to me with the *Bolts.framework* and *Parse.framework*. Both were added in the git repo already, so adding them back did not fixed the issue. I had to remove first:

```
cd MyApp/SDK/
git rm -r Parse.framework/
git rm -r Bolts.framework/
```

The I had to copy them again in the SDK/ folder and adding to git

```
 cd MyApp/SDK/
 git add .
 git commit * -m "Maintenance: Fixed git error unable to index file"
```

Comment: I managed to make it work by doing "git add" for the files under Bolts.framework and followed by "git commit" command line.  Strange that I cannot do this under the Xcode UI.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with IntelliJ IDEA. An error popup appeared when I tried to commit with the IDE git plugin. Probably this is related to the fact that I had staged a path that was previously a file but now is a directory, and have that previous file moved to the new directory.

Suppose that path is `bin/yii`. What I did was:

- Rename the directory to something different, e.g. `bin/yii-temp`
- Commit the directory and its contents
- Rename the directory back to `bin/yii`
- Commit with `--amend` what I had just committed.

Comment: Reported this as a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196361

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! :-)
Was exactly the case: I had deleted my gulpfile.js and created a folder with the same name (see https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/javascript-and-gulpfiles).

Comment: Although `amend` didn't work for me. I just commited one more time.